# Can I send a New Account Notification to a newly created user's secondary email?

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-directory-api

I am creating a new user using google-api-client directory v1 api in Python. I am using a sha-1 of the password as recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert). Is there a way to automatically send a 'new account notification' to the new users secondary or alternative email to give them access to their new account. When this is done from G Suite, the URL is approx. 200 chars long.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think I'm dependent on the functionality being there in the API, but it is not obvious. I've searched extensively. G-suite sends an email with a long embedded link which has a limited 'valid life'. So Google has the functionality to generate this URL, my question centers around if they share that with API (admin) users via their API.

Comment: Update and definitive answer, I had also raised a case with Google and they have told me that, although this functionality exists in G-suite, it is not exposed in the Directory API. Therefore, it is necessary to send the login details via email to a new user, or use some 'password reset' workflow. I will send them a feature request for this.